# From Two Tables Set Flag between Data Range in R

Tags: r

I have two datasets Table A and Table B. Both table keys are Item.

I'm working on an R script that would set the flag column in table A to "x" if it falls in the date range from table B.

I tried using the between function from dplyr getting an error message of "expecting a single value" on my original dataset.

```
Table A     
Item    Date    Flag
Test1   1/1/2018    
Test1   1/2/2018    x
Test1   1/3/2018    x
Test1   1/4/2018    x
Test1   1/5/2018    
Test2   1/6/2018    
Test2   1/7/2018    x
Test2   1/8/2018    

Table B
Item    Sdate   Edate
Test 1  1/2/2018    1/4/2018
Test 2  1/7/2018    1/7/2018
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with `dplyr`...

```
library(dplyr)

TableA %>% left_join(TableB) %>% #merge in the TableB information
  mutate(Flag=c("","x")[1+(as.Date(Date) >= as.Date(Sdate) & 
                           as.Date(Date) <= as.Date(Edate))]) %>% 
  select(Item,Date,Flag) #remove the TableB columns

  Item     Date Flag
1 Test1 1/1/2018     
2 Test1 1/2/2018    x
3 Test1 1/3/2018    x
4 Test1 1/4/2018    x
5 Test1 1/5/2018     
6 Test2 1/6/2018     
7 Test2 1/7/2018    x
8 Test2 1/8/2018
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with non-equi joins available in the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

table_a <- as.data.table(table_a)
table_b <- as.data.table(table_b)

# Need to convert dates to Date class if not type Date already:
table_a[, Date := as.Date(Date)]
table_b[, Sdate := as.Date(Sdate)]
table_b[, Edate := as.Date(Edate)]

# Make sure the values in the Item column can be joined ("Test 1" should be "Test1") 
table_b[, Item := gsub(" ", "", Item)]

# Create a new empty flag column
table_a[, Flag := ""]

# Non-equi join, match rows where the value in the Item column is the same and the
# value in the Date column is between the Sdate and Edate, 
# then update the flag column for those rows in table_a
table_a[table_b, on = .(Item, Date >= Sdate, Date <= Edate), Flag := "x"]
```